# Voting system: mysql query to check if user voted

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Bascially I am developing a simple system in which user can upvote or downvote an article and I would like to be able to check if the user already voted. My Mysql table looks more or less as follows:

```
id   author_id   posit_id vote
1       99         1       1
2       88         2       -1
3       99         3       1
4       88         4       1
```

I insert the vote using the following code:

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_post_votes (author_id, post_id, vote) VALUES ('$user_ID', '$id', '$vote')"  );
```

Now, I would like to write a code in php that checks if the given user has already voted on a given post (based on post_id). I've started with:

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
```

I tried various queries but I am not sure how to proceed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is your voting system working only for logged in user?

Comment: yes, it only works for logged_in users

Comment: Thanks Petroff but this doesnt checks if he voted on a given post, just in general if he voted.

Comment: is the 'author_id' the author of the post or the user_id of the voter?

Comment: user id of the voter, sorry I should make it clear

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT vote FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id='postId' AND author_id = 'authorID'
```

and instead of postID and authorID insert real values you would like to check. And if you get any result you'll know that user has voted and you'll get value of vote field. And if you don't get any row for result - user didn't vote.

Comment: add limit 1 at the end for performences. If he find the results its pointless to continue searching.

Comment: It should not be possible to vote more than once for same post, if I got it right.

Comment: Ye but sql do not know there are not more results and will continue to searching. Your select can return 1 results or more than one, so limit 1 is the better way. And count(vote) is what he need.

Comment: I would do that check on writing to database...First delete records with specific user id and post id and then insert new one. There is no point keeping it in database if it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a select query with count column. Exemple :

```
SELECT count(author_id) as already_voted FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id='postId' AND author_id = 'authorID';
```

Then, compare the results : If row['already_voted'] == 0, he never voted. Else, if row['already_voted'] < 0, he already voted.